# Getting error 1064 while running the following procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, relational, insert-into

When I am executing this procedure I am getting the below error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

```
    delimiter //
    CREATE PROCEDURE insert_organization_position_master()BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE job_id INTEGER(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE orgId INTEGER(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE postitle varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE jobtype INTEGER(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE degreeId INTEGER(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE minexp INTEGER(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE maxexp INTEGER(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE resp Text DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE skills varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE salmin varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE salmax varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE certifications INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE occdetail varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE jobfamily INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE posmasterId VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE docids VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL;

    DEClARE position_cursor CURSOR FOR 

    select j.JOB_IDENTIFIER, j.JOB_ORGANIZATION_IDENTIFIER, j.POSITION_TITLE, j.JOB_TYPE_IDENTIFIER,
    j.REQUIRED_DEGREE_TYPE_IDENTIFIER, j.MIN_EXP, j.MAX_EXP, j.RESPONSIBILITIES, j.JOB_SKILL_KEYWORDS,
    j.SALARY_MIN, j.SALARY_MAX, j.CERTIFICATIONS_MANDATORY, j.OCC_DETAILED_ID, j.MAJOR_GROUP_ID 
    from job j 
        where j.POSITION_TITLE is not null  
                    and j.JOB_IDENTIFIER  in(47346, 47347)   
            group by j.POSITION_TITLE, j.JOB_ORGANIZATION_IDENTIFIER 
                order by  j.JOB_IDENTIFIER desc;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
OPEN position_cursor;


get_position: LOOP

    FETCH position_cursor INTO job_id, orgId, postitle, jobtype, degreeId, minexp, maxexp, resp, skills, 
            salmin, salmax, certifications, occdetail, jobfamily;
    IF finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE get_position;
    END IF;

insert into organization_position_master(ORGANIZATION_IDENTIFIER, POSTIION_TITLE, JOB_TYPE_IDENTIFIER, MIN_EDUCATION, MIN_EXPERIENCE, MAX_EXPERIENCE, RESPONSIBILITIES, JOB_SPECIFIC_KEYWORDS, MIN_SALARY, MAX_SALARY, PROFESSIONAL_LICENSE_REQUIRED, ACTIVE, ACTIVE_DATE) 
             values (orgId, postitle, jobtype, degreeId, minexp, maxexp, resp, skills, salmin, salmax, certifications, 1, NOW());

select max(ORGANIZATION_POSTION_MASTER_ID) into posmasterId 
        from  organization_position_master;

insert into organization_position_master_job_families (ORGANIZATION_POSTION_MASTER_ID, JOB_FAMILY_ID) 
        values (posmasterId, jobfamily);

IF (occdetail is not null) THEN 
    SET @values = REPLACE(occdetail, ',', CONCAT(', ', posmasterId, '),('));
    SET @values = CONCAT('(', @values, ', ', @posmasterId, ')'); 
    SET @insert = CONCAT('INSERT INTO organization_position_master_job_occupations VALUES', @values);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @insert;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;

select group_concat(DOCUMENT_TYPE_IDENTIFIER) into docids from job_documents_requirement where JOB_IDENTIFIER = docids;

IF (docids is not null) THEN 
    SET @values = REPLACE(docids, ',', CONCAT(', ', posmasterId, '),('));
    SET @values = CONCAT('(', @values, ', ', @posmasterId, ')'); 
    SET @insert = CONCAT('INSERT INTO organization_position_master_attachments VALUES', @values);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @insert;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;
END LOOP get_position;

CLOSE position_cursor;
END//
delimiter ;
```

I tried adding delimeter. But no hopes.Could please tell me anybody what was wrong with my procedure.

Comment: You are getting _what_? An error? An exception? Please fix your question ;-)

Comment: edit your question with the delimiter because in this example its the delimier issue ofcourse..

Comment: Finally I got it. I should not make use of @posmasterId. And should use posmasterId. Thanks for all.